# Node.js Mongoose method find({}) retrieve nothing

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Hello I'm trying to get all entries from my MongoDB collection Piloti, but when I execute the following method the array piloti is void:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Piloti = require("./models/Piloti")

app.get("/piloti", async (req, res, next) => {
  const piloti = await Piloti.find({});
  console.log("Piloti:", piloti);
  res.status(200).json({ piloti: piloti });
});
```

Here I declared my model Piloti, all db columns are saved in MongoDB as String, and I checked all field names, including capital letter:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const PilotiSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  Pilota: String,
  Nazionalita: String,
  Eta: String,
  Team: String,
  Punti: String,
  Bahrain: String,
  Arabia_Saudita: String,
  Australia: String,
  Imola: String,
  Miami: String,
  Spagna: String,
  Monaco: String,
  Azerbaigian: String,
  Canada: String,
  Gran_Bretagna: String,
  Austria: String,
  Francia: String,
  Ungheria: String,
  Belgio: String,
  Olanda: String,
  Italia: String,
  Singapore: String,
  Giappone: String,
  Stati_Uniti: String,
  Messico: String,
  Brasile: String,
  Abu_Dhabi: String,
});

const Piloti = mongoose.model("Piloti", PilotiSchema);

module.exports = Piloti;
```

This is my db connection:

```
mongoose.set("strictQuery", false);
mongoose.connect(
  "mongodb+srv://<username:pwd@url>/?retryWrites=true&w=majority",
  {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
  }
);

const connection = mongoose.connection;

connection.on("connected", function () {
  console.log("Database connesso");
});
connection.on("disconnected", function () {
  console.log("Database disconnesso");
});
connection.on("Errore", console.error.bind(console, "Errore di connessione:"));
```

Comment: Did you add the database name to the connection string? https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html

Comment: yes I setup the connection String correctly

Comment: Just to be clear, I wasn't referring to the address of the cluster. You would be getting some kind of error if you weren't successfully connecting to something. Instead I was talking about the logical database name, part of the namespace, which the collection belongs to. By default clients connect to the `test` database. Queries against nonexistent collections return empty results rather than error

Comment: Make sure 1. Connect to the correct database. 2.  There have collection and documents in that database